# Keras example: mnist_siamese_graph - Accuracy doesn't seems correct

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

The keras example used in keras/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py doesn't look correct.
The function below is not a real accuracy (accuracy = (correctly predicted class / total testing class) )

```
def compute_accuracy(predictions, labels):
    '''Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    return labels[predictions.ravel() < 0.5].mean()
```

Besides that, we have [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4980) issue, which makes me think that the contrastive_loss and get_pairs function are wrong too. Can someone give an explanation for this accuracy metric and those functions?

Comment: I found out that this 'compute_accuracy' function is computing the precision.  The correct one is "np.mean(np.equal(predictions.ravel() < 0.5, labels))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [compute_accuracy function is wrong](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5963). It's currently computing the precision. It should be:

```
def compute_precision(predictions, labels):
    '''Compute classification precision with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    return labels[predictions.ravel() < 0.5].mean()


def compute_accuracy(predictions, labels):
    '''Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    return np.mean(np.equal(predictions.ravel() < 0.5, labels))
```

I'm not sure yet about [this issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4980), but fixing the accuracy function seems to be working fine.